# sass @if variable-exists import else error message

Tags: sass

I wanna know if it is possible to me get a message or alert in my terminal saying the font was not loaded, is that possible? right now I am not getting any error message.

**font variable:**

```
$font-url: 'http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:100,300,400,700,900';
```

if conditional

**// Import if Google Fonts URL is defined**

```
@if variable-exists(font-url) {
      @import url($font-url);
}
```

Comment: I don't think that is possible. Sass compiles before runtime and the font is loaded on runtime.

Comment: You should do that using JavaScript ajax, I think.

Comment: it's possible I found a solution :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution for this:

```
$font-url: unquote("somefile.css");
@if variable-exists(font-url) {
  @import url($font-url);
} @else {
  @error "sorry no dice";
}
```

Comment: This only checks whether there is a variable with name `$font-url`. It doesn't check whether the path provided exists or not. In your case, always the `if` condition will trigger.